# Magento: get a list of attribute values

Tags: list, magento, attributes, widget

I am new to Magento and I'm building a bookshop. I have an attribute called author, and I would like to show a list of all authors (a list of their attribute values). I tried to create a widget and use this code in it but it returns me an empty array. How can I achieve this? Where should I place the code, in a widget, a block?

```
protected function _toHtml()
{

    $name='author';
    $attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
    $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
    $attributeOptions = $attributeInfo->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 

    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach($attributeOptions as $opt)
        $html .= '<li>'.$opt[0].'</li>';
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        echo $value
    }
}
```

you can get attribute with this code just write this code in `view.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, your code worked quite good for a particular product, however i finally get what I wanted using this:

```
$attributeCode='author';
// build and filter the product collection
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('notnull' => true))
->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('neq' => ''))
->addAttributeToSelect($attributeCode);

// get all distinct attribute values
$usedAttributeValues = array_unique($products->getColumnValues($attributeCode));
sort($usedAttributeValues);
```